# Magento : Error in payment redirect page

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, javascript

When I Click on `Place Order` button I get this error message on console:

```
.prototype.js:828 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined
```

and Order was not placed.
[image]